# Question about the no-endorsment clause on the BSD license

Tags: licensing, legal, bsd-license

I'm developing a non-free library and I want to use Bcrypt.Net in it. The clause in question:

- Neither the name of BCrypt.Net nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

To what extent does this mean I can't use the name of Bcrypt.Net? For instance, could I say "the only ASP.Net authentication library capable of using Bcrypt" or can I even include "supports Bcrypt for password hashing" in promotional materials?

Note: I do not actually modify any of Bcrypt.Net's code

Comment: If your business depends on this, you *really* need to go talk to an attorney.

Comment: Sounds like standard boilerplate legalese. Did a google search and found it on a couple different sites.

Comment: @Peter It's just a small project I'm trying to sell in my free time.

Comment: Since I don't modify(or even distribute) any of Bcrypt's code, aren't I immune from this clause? The phrase I'm seeing is "products derived from"

Comment: Maybe you can do what you want to do, maybe you can't, but the point is that you are asking a question that *cannot* be answered by geeks, no matter how smart they are. If you want to avoid paying someone, you could try sending a description of your intended use of the name to the copyright holder and ask if it's OK with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gosh I would think you can't use the name to promote your software. Have you thought of just emailing and asking for permission for the exact usage you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I think Bcrypt itself is an algorithm, while Bcrypt.net is the name of the library. I don't think you can use the latter in such promotional sentences, but definitely the former.

Disclaimer: IANAL, unless you should decide to follow Jeremy's advice and ask for permission, you should better consult a lawyer.